# How to split a String into integers?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, integer

I'd like to split a String, and store each digit of the String into an integer.

Here's my test code:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int firstGuessDigit, secondGuessDigit, thirdGuessDigit, fourthGuessDigit;
        String guess = "1234";
        String[] parts = guess.split("\");
        firstGuessDigit = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        secondGuessDigit = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        thirdGuessDigit = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        fourthGuessDigit = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
    }

}
```

When I run the program, I get an error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at test.main(test.java:11)

Comment: Why not use the String method `toCharArray`?

Comment: String[] parts = guess.toCharArray();

Comment: @AntonH if I use this method, can I access each digit separately?

Comment: Yes, you can. Look at my answer.

Comment: What happened to your previous question? The one about seeing decimal output? You never responded to my comments.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I figured out the problem on my own after I posted. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String#toCharArray` instead:

```
char[] parts = guess.toCharArray();
firstGuessDigit = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(parts[0]));
secondGuessDigit = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(parts[1]));
thirdGuessDigit = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(parts[2]));
fourthGuessDigit = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(parts[3]));
```

Comment: This can still throw an exception of java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if str is changed correct way to do it is looping through it. like it is done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26434013/1085186)

Comment: @wrongAnswer I tend to stay as close as possible to OPs answer. If they don't use a loop, neither do I. But yes, loop would be better ("correct" is debateable). And I was too lazy to add `try...catch` code.

Answer (score 2):

The error you getting is because you are trying to do parts[1] when it doesn't have it.

Code you are looking for is:

```
String guess = "1234";
int[] guessInteger = new int[guess.length()];
int i=0;
for(Character ch : guess.toCharArray()){
    if(Character.isDigit(ch)){
        guessInteger[i++] = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simply `int[] guessInteger = guess.chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).toArray();`

Comment: @dusky We need to understand OP is obviously a beginner. So kept it simple for them to understand and debug through it.

Comment: There is no need to convert the `Character` to a `String` and call `Integer.parseInt`. You can get the numeric value with either `Character.getNumericValue(ch)` or `Character.digit(ch, 10)`.

Comment: @wrongAnswer It **is** simple. Although lambdas are new to Java they're not hard to understand. A lot of JavaScript or C# people use lambdas right from the start. Lambdas are now part of Java, they were added to make things easier so use them.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the characters of the string using the `chars()` stream and map them to their numeric values with `Character.getNumericValue`:

```
"1234".chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).toArray()
```

If you prefer to get them as a list instead of an array, you can use:

```
"1234".chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int firstGuessDigit, secondGuessDigit, thirdGuessDigit, fourthGuessDigit;
        String guess = "1234";

        String[] parts = new String[4];
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            parts[i] = ""+guess.charAt(i);
        }

        firstGuessDigit = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        secondGuessDigit = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        thirdGuessDigit = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        fourthGuessDigit = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`("%-11s%03d%n")%` : used as a formatter.

- `-`: minus sign used for left indentation of the string.
- `11s`: here 11 denotes the string's minimum field width 11.
- `0`: pads the extra 0s in the integer.
- `3d`: here 3 denotes integer's minimum field width 3.
- `%n`: prints the new line.

Hope, this helps!

Comment: Please explain your answer with a working code sample.